415 Unsupported Media Type - POST http://localhost:5229/api/Login/Register 415 (Unsupported Media Type)
I am designing a Login page. This page contains Login and Register operations. Login works without any problems. And since the login is successful, it redirects to Home/index. But when I create a record in Register ;
{
"type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13",
"title": "Unsupported Media Type",
"status": 415,
"traceId": "00-cc6baa3aa36de0096173305b5da0fc3c-a1c304fae207b3f0-00"
}
I am encountering such an error. When I put a break point in my Login Controllers, I noticed that the request never came here. Neither foody nor the loginController in foodyService receives the request.
Foody/Controller/LoginController
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Foody.Models;
using Foody.Helpers;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace Foody.Controllers
{
    // Bu controller, kullanıcı giriş ve kayıt işlemlerini yönetir.
    public class LoginController : Controller
    {
        // Giriş sayfasını gösteren GET isteği.
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // Yeni kullanıcı kaydı gerçekleştiren POST isteği.
        [HttpPost("Register")]
        public IActionResult Register(UserModel model)
        {
            // ModelState, modelin geçerli olup olmadığını kontrol eder.
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(new ResponseModel
                {
                    Result = false,
                    ErrorMessage = "Model doğrulaması başarısız.",
                    ErrorCode = "Register-1001" // Model doğrulama hatası için örnek hata kodu.
                });
            }

            try
            {
                // API'ye POST isteği gönderilir ve sonuç alınır.
                var response = ServiceManager.MakeRequest(HttpRequestType.POST, "Login/Register", model);

                // Eğer kayıt başarılıysa ana sayfaya yönlendirilir.
                if (response.Result)   // false dönüyor!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                {
                    // Kayıt başarısızsa hata mesajı döndürülür.
                    return BadRequest(new ResponseModel
                    {
                        Result = false,
                        ErrorMessage = "Kayıt yapılamadı: " + response.ErrorMessage,
                        ErrorCode = "Register-1002" // Kayıt hatası için örnek hata kodu.
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Kayıt sırasında bir hata oluşursa genel hata mesajı döndürülür.
                return BadRequest(new ResponseModel
                {
                    Result = false,
                    ErrorMessage = $"Bir hata oluştu: {ex.Message}",
                    ErrorCode = "Register-1003" // Genel hata durumu için örnek hata kodu.
                });
            }
        }

        // Giriş işlemini gerçekleştiren POST isteği.
        [HttpPost("LoginIndex")]
        public IActionResult Index(UserLoginModel model)
        {
            // ModelState, modelin geçerli olup olmadığını kontrol eder.
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // API'ye POST isteği gönderilir ve sonuç alınır.
                var response = ServiceManager.MakeRequest(HttpRequestType.POST, "Login/LoginIndex", model);

                // Eğer giriş başarılıysa ana sayfaya yönlendirilir.

                if (response.Result)// false dönüyor!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                else
                {
                    // Giriş başarısızsa hata mesajı döndürülür.
                    return BadRequest(new ResponseModel
                    {
                        Result = false,
                        ErrorMessage = "Geçersiz giriş denemesi: " + response.ErrorMessage,
                        ErrorCode = "Login-1003" // Hata durumunda döndürülen örnek hata kodu.
                    });
                }
            }

            // Model geçerli değilse hata mesajı döndürülür.
            return BadRequest(new ResponseModel
            {
                Result = false,
                ErrorMessage = "Model doğrulaması başarısız.",
                ErrorCode = "Login-1004" // Model doğrulama hatası için örnek hata kodu.
            });
        }


    }
}

FoodyService/Controller/LoginController

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using FoodyService.DTO.Models;
using System.Linq;
using FoodyService.Models;

namespace FoodyService.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class LoginController : ControllerBase
    {
        // Yeni kullanıcı kaydı yapılmasını sağlayan metod
        [HttpPost("Register")]
        public IActionResult Register(UserModel user)
        {
            // Geri dönüş modeli oluşturuluyor
            ResponseModel resp = new ResponseModel()
            {
                Result = false
            };

            using (FoodyDbContext dbContext = new FoodyDbContext())
            {
                // Eğer kullanıcı bilgileri null ise, hata döndürülüyor
                if (user == null)
                {
                    resp.ErrorCode = "Register-1001";
                    resp.ErrorMessage = "Parametre hatası: Kullanıcı bilgileri eksik.";

                    return BadRequest(resp);
                }

                // Şifre karmaşıklığı kontrolü yapılıyor
                if (!IsComplexPassword(user.Password))
                {
                    resp.ErrorCode = "Register-1002";
                    resp.ErrorMessage = "Şifre yeterince karmaşık değil. Lütfen şifrenizi daha karmaşık yapınız.";

                    return BadRequest(resp);
                }

                try
                {
                    // Aynı email adresine sahip bir kullanıcı olup olmadığını kontrol ediyoruz
                    if (dbContext.Users.Any(u => u.Email == user.Email))
                    {
                        resp.ErrorCode = "Register-1003";
                        resp.ErrorMessage = "Bu email adresi ile zaten bir kullanıcı mevcut.";

                        return BadRequest(resp);
                    }

                    // Yeni kullanıcı oluşturuluyor
                    User checkedUser = new User()
                    {
                        FirstName = user.FirstName,
                        LastName = user.LastName,
                        Email = user.Email,
                        Password = user.Password,
                        UserId = user.UserId
                    };

                    // Yeni kullanıcı veritabanına ekleniyor
                    dbContext.Users.Add(checkedUser);
                    dbContext.SaveChanges();

                    // Kayıt işlemi başarılı, geri dönüş başarılı olarak ayarlanıyor
                    resp.Result = true;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // Bir hata oluştuğunda hata mesajı ve kodu döndürülüyor
                    resp.ErrorCode = "Register-1004";
                    resp.ErrorMessage = $"Kişi oluşturulurken bir hata oluştu: {ex.Message}";

                    return BadRequest(resp);
                }
            }

            return Ok(resp);
        }

        // Kullanıcının giriş yapmasını sağlayan metod
        [HttpPost("LoginIndex")]
        public IActionResult LoginIndex(UserLoginModel model)
        {
            using (FoodyDbContext dbContext = new FoodyDbContext())
            {
                // Veritabanında kullanıcıyı email ve şifreye göre arıyoruz
                var user = dbContext.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.Email == model.Username && u.Password == model.Password);

                // Eğer kullanıcı bulunduysa, başarılı giriş
                if (user != null)
                {
                    return Ok(new ResponseModel
                    {
                        Result = true,
                        ErrorMessage = null
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    // Kullanıcı bulunamadıysa, hata döndürülüyor
                    ResponseModel resp = new ResponseModel()
                    {
                        Result = false,
                        ErrorCode = "Login-1003",
                        ErrorMessage = "Kullanıcı adı veya şifre hatalı."
                    };

                    // Unauthorized (Yetkisiz) durumu dönüyoruz
                    return Unauthorized(resp);
                }
            }
        }

        // Şifre karmaşıklığı kontrolü yapan yardımcı metod
        private bool IsComplexPassword(string password)
        {
            // Şifre uzunluğu en az 8 karakter olmalı
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(password) || password.Length < 8)
                return false;

            // Şifrede büyük harf, küçük harf, rakam ve özel karakter olup olmadığı kontrol ediliyor
            bool hasUpperCase = password.Any(char.IsUpper);
            bool hasLowerCase = password.Any(char.IsLower);
            bool hasDigit = password.Any(char.IsDigit);
            bool hasSpecialChar = password.Any(ch => !char.IsLetterOrDigit(ch));

            // Tüm kontrollerden geçerse şifre karmaşık kabul ediliyor
            return hasUpperCase && hasLowerCase && hasDigit && hasSpecialChar;
        }
    }
}



ServiceManager
using Foody.Models;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;

namespace Foody.Helpers
{
    public static class ServiceManager
    {
        // HttpClient nesnesini oluşturur ve temel ayarlarını yapar
        private static HttpClient GetClient()
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient
            {
                BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:5130")
            };

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            return client;
        }

        // API'ye istek gönderir ve bir ResponseModel döner (Senkron versiyon)
        public static ResponseModel MakeRequest(HttpRequestType requestType, string apiPath, object param = null)
        {
            var result = new ResponseModel
            {
                Result = false,
                ErrorMessage = "ERR-001: Bir şeyler ters gitti! Lütfen daha sonra tekrar deneyin!"
            };

            try
            {
                apiPath = "api/" + apiPath;

                using (var client = GetClient())
                {
                    HttpResponseMessage response;

                    if (requestType == HttpRequestType.GET)
                    {
                        response = client.GetAsync(apiPath).Result;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(param);
                        var content = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                        response = client.PostAsync(apiPath, content).Result;
                    }

                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        var content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                        result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseModel>(content);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result.ErrorMessage = $"API isteği başarısız oldu: {response.ReasonPhrase}";
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                result.Result = false;
                result.ErrorMessage = $"Exception: {ex.Message}";
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}


When the user creates a record, the change moves from Login/index.cshtml to the Home/index.cshtml page.

You should share the client's code that is consuming this code (HTML form, fetch JS, or another one). I guess you're most likely passing the parameters with an invalid content-type.

The "415 Unsupported Media Type" error usually indicates that the data format being sent is not supported by the server. Make sure you are using the correct format when sending the request.  Please show me the request header, you can open the browser's developer tools( Typically, press the F12 key or right-click and select "Inspect"),  then go to the "Network" tab, click on the request in the request list, and check the "Headers" section to find the Content-Type header and verify if it is application/json.

Without knowing how you area calling the AJAX endpoint it is impossible to know what the exact problem is.
I have seen this type of error repeated when invoking a generic "Post" AJAX transaction using jQuery. What has worked for me is to precede the parameter to the AJAX method with "[FromForm]" like
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromForm] DataViewModel data, CancellationToken token){ ... }

